# How to mute downlink (speaker) audio in Android

Tags: android, audio, kernel, android-source, mute

As in title, how do I mute audio from incoming call? I'm interested in any kind of solution, using API from SDK, NDK, or even modifying AOSP kernel sources and recompiling them, perhaps exposing a new interface.

Comment: Do you mean the microphone or the speaker?

Comment: You you mean muting audio on a player when there's an incoming call?

Comment: @DanS: I mean speaker audio

Comment: @Merlevede: I mean muting the voice call (person calling you).

Answer (score 1):

Use [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_VOICE_CALL) with  `STREAM_VOICE_CALL` and method `setStreamVolume` to control the volume of the speaker for the incoming caller.